# Shared preference not saved or loop does'nt work

Tags: java, android, loops, sharedpreferences, shared

Some help would be most thankful for. I have two activities. MainActivity and SharedPrefs. I want the app on open to look if there is some saved preferences. If not it must go to another activity which ask for some detail. Then on pressing the submit button it must save the shared preference and go to the MainActivity. But it doesn't, it just jumps back to the SharedPrefs activity. Now I don't know if my shared preference is not being saved (I thought "editor.commit" will do the job), or is there something wrong with my loop. I did change my loop around, and it is working the other way around, but I can have the whole thing wrong since I'm quite new to Android and Java. Like I said, some help will be appreciated.

Here is my MainActivity with my loop:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean check = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("Check",false);
        if(!check){
            //Intent intent;
            Intent SharedPrefsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SharedPrefs.class);
            startActivity(SharedPrefsIntent); }
        else {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            TextView brands = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.brands);
            brands.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent brandsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, brands.class);
                startActivity(brandsIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And here is my SharedPrefs where I try to get some info to add to the shared preferences:

```
public class SharedPrefs extends AppCompatActivity {
//public static Context context;
EditText ed1,ed2,ed3;
Button b1;

public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
public static final String Name = "nameKey";
public static final String Phone = "phoneKey";
public static final String Email = "emailKey";

SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.shared_prefs);

    ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    ed2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    ed3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);

    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String n  = ed1.getText().toString();
            String ph  = ed2.getText().toString();
            String e  = ed3.getText().toString();

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

            editor.putString(Name, n);
            editor.putString(Phone, ph);
            editor.putString(Email, e);
            editor.commit();

            Toast.makeText(SharedPrefs.this,"Thanks",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent BackToMainIntent = new Intent(SharedPrefs.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(BackToMainIntent);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Where is the loop you refer to?

Comment: Were is the loop you are reffering. And you are not saving any check value in sharedprefernce which you are checking in mainactivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add "Check" key value to SharedPreferences after setting your desired values as it's always return false on MainActivity.

You may also use .apply() instead of .commit().

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you are saving a Boolean `Check` anywhere in the second activity. So in your first activity, this Boolean never exists and you are getting the default value which you have set to `false`. You need a preference called `Check' to be set to true in your second activity.

Answer (score 0):

In your SharedPrefs Activity
Change your this piece of code

```
        editor.putString(Name, n);
        editor.putString(Phone, ph);
        editor.putString(Email, e);
        editor.commit();
```

With

```
        editor.putString(Name, n);
        editor.putString(Phone, ph);
        editor.putString(Email, e);
        editor.putBooleon (Check,true);
        editor.commit();
```

Then It will work as you want.

Happy coding :)